# ansible stat check last modified time

Tags: linux, ansible, stat

I have a situation where I need to check the last modified date for a file using ansible. Normally stat in linux has the properties for the file like Modified,access and changed. I know p.stat.isdir and p.stat.pw_name exist but do we have a similar option using ansible stat to check last modified date of a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible has a module with the same name [`stat`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html).

Its return values contain `mtime` which is what you are looking for.

> **mtime**
>     Time of last modification
>     **Returned**: success, path exists and user can read stats

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#return-stat/mtime*</sup>